# Bash script; how to use vars and funcs defined after command

Tags: linux, bash, function, variables

How to use variables or functions that are defined after the command.

*Variable*

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello "$who"
who="World"
```

*Function*

```
#!/bin/bash

function_name

function_name() {
echo Hello World
}
```

I also heard there is a command to read entire bash script before executing any commands, this would work for my case. But it would be nice if there is a more pinpoint way.

**More in-depth**

```
#!/bin/bash

h=Hello

echo $h "$who"

var1=World

who=$(cat <<HEREDOC
You
Me
$var1
HEREDOC
)
```

Comment: You can't declare and use functions before the definition like you can in C. Why are you trying to do this? Do you just want the functions/variables defined at the end of the script for readability?

Comment: @thatotherguy You are correct, I have a heredoc in the script and would like it to be below the command.

Comment: I don't follow. Do you have a here doc with variables in it, and you want the variables to be defined further down? Can you just use functions, like `main() { echo "Hello $who"; };   ...; who="world"; main` ?

Comment: @thatotherguy You are correct again, I want variables in the here doc and generally just at the bottom of the command for readability. Both the command and here doc are large... Also to note, I do have vars before the command and I don't want to point to an external doc.

Comment: Would using a method like I suggested be an option? There's no way to get around the fact that you have to define functions/variables before they're used, but you can control flow in those kinds of ways

Comment: @SongJaeGu Why do you think theres a problem? Your script givng a right otput after execution - "Hello
You
Me
World"

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks! I'm getting an error, but it's unrelated. If you want to answer the question, I'll check it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables and functions always have to be defined before use. This is because function definitions are actually commands that assign the name in the current context, and not like in C where they merely provide an implementation for a name.

You can instead use control flow to ensure that the definitions execute before your code, regardless of their relative layout in the file:

```
main() {
  echo "Hello $var"
}

var="world"
main
```